# load different class of same type based on name

Tags: c#

This is a really simple structure question, but i don't know what is the best way to do this in C#.

I need a "base" class or something to allow me load diferent "levels" in the "level" object, and changing the name I can swith the class what I want to use.

Now i'm using a abstract class and instance of the childrens in this way:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Level : MonoBehaviour {

    public levelClass level;

    public void initLevel(string className) {

        Type t = Type.GetType(className);
        level = (levelClass)Activator.CreateInstance(t, new object[] { });
        level.Start();

    }

    void Start () {

        Debug.Log("Levels: Start");
        initLevel("worldTwo");

    }

    void Update () {

        level.Update();

    }

}

public abstract class levelClass {

    public abstract void Start();
    public abstract void Update();

}

public class worldOne : levelClass {

    public override void Start() {
        Debug.Log("worldOne: Start");
    }

    public override void Update() {
        Debug.Log("worldOne: Update");
    }

}

public class worldTwo : levelClass
{

    public override void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("worldTwo: Start!");
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("worldTwo: Update!");
    }

}
```

But I think exists better ways to do, like store all classes in a list and call it or something similar. The part i don't like nothing is have some classes public in this file (I know i can split in other files, i'm trying to think only in a way to do this better)

Comment: It sounds like you want to implement some polymorphism?  Is that right?

Comment: yes, something similar

Comment: might need some more detail, but, theres lots of c# examples of polymorphism on the internet.